# Changing JS Code from Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to draw a chart on my website. Here is the js code for the chart with sample inputs

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];//these are sample
      $.plot("#placeholder", [d2]);
       });
</script>
```

Here is what i wanna do. I want to take some information from the database and put it to the chart. I wrote down the code for taking information. But i couldn't manage how to insert them to the js code for the chart.

```
using (var db = new Entities())
{ var q = from u in db.Sites
          where u.SiteURL == result.SiteURL
          select u;
if (q.Any()) {
        List<webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites> l = new List<webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites>();
        l = q.OrderByDescending(s => s.CheckDate).Take(10).ToList();
        webpagespeedtest_flat.DataModel.Sites[] z = l.ToArray();
int x = z.Count();
for( int i=0; i < z.Count(); i++){
 z[i].Score; // --> this will be the first attribute(x)
 z[i].CheckDate;// -->this will be the second attribute(y)
}
```

Comment: WebForms or MVC?

Comment: I'm not using MVC. So, WebForms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using MVC, there are two ways you could do this. One is to use razor to emit the correct javascript that you need when the page is rendered. The other (neater) way is to make a call that returns JSON which is then used to populate the chart.

Comment: Well, i am not using MVC. Actually, i am not a pro on programming. So i don't even know how can i work with these solution methods. I'm sorry. Is there any other way you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use from c# like this.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append(@"$(function () {");
    sb.Append(@"var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];");
    sb.Append(@"$.plot(\""#placeholder\"", [d2]);");
    sb.Append(@"});");
    sb.Append(@"</script>");
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ChangeChart", sb.ToString(), false);
```

Sorry if i can not help you.

Comment: It's not a wrong code. But why would i do that? It is not the answer to my question if im not wrong. I'm trying to put z[] attributes to the d2 variable.

Comment: You are cannot change the string in StringBuilder? Changing string inside string builder how you would. You are not writing which chart you use? Sorry if I can not help you.